# Issue with group by laravel and sql

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Firstly I have problem which count products which are sold every day. In sql I have query

```
select product_name, sum(quantity) as quantity from invoice_product 
join invoices on invoices.id = invoice_product.invoice_id
join products on products.id = invoice_product.product_id
 where invoices.issued_at = '2019-05-16' 
 and products.`made_by_us` = 1
 group by product_name
```

It show me interesting for me information but I used `product_name` to make `group by` but I should use `product_id` - I need show name too but I don't know how to do it.

Secondly I want to use it in Laravel so maybe someone know which is it possible to do it in Eloquent?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with `withCount()` combined with `select(DB::raw())`, like this:

```php
$products = Product::withCount(['invoices as quantity' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('sum(quantity)'));
}])->get();
```

Then, you can access each quantity sum like this:

```php
$quantity = $products->first()->quantity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to update your model relationships to achieve that.

Models:

`InvoiceProduct` Model

```
class InvoiceProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'invoice_product';

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];
}

public function invoice()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice'); // Assuming `Invoice` Model is directly in app folder
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product'); // Assuming `Product` Model is directly in app folder
}
```

Controller:

```
$full_query = InvoiceProduct::whereHas('invoice', function ($query) {
   return $query->where('issued_at', '2019-05-16');
})->whereHas('product', function ($query) {
   return $query->where('made_by_us', 1);
});

$product_names = $full_query->get(['product_name']);
$total_quantities = $full_query->sum('quantity');
```

Comment: Tank you, It's work very well but I need one thing in different way, I need `product_name` and `quantity` this product not all of products, I try do it by myself by if you have time please give mi directions. The best solution it could be `$product_names = $full_query->get(['product_name'], sum['quantity']);` but it isn't working.

Comment: i think you need to group by product id

Comment: Try `$product_names = $full_query->select('product_name', \DB::raw('SUM(quantity) as quantity'))->get()`